# javascript referring to an array syntax

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, syntax

What is the correct syntax to refer to the first element in an array, when there are numbered arrays like so?

```
someArray1["someString", "anotherString"];
someArray2["someString", "anotherString"];
someArray3["someString", "anotherString"];

heresANumber = 1;
grabAString(heresANumber);

function grabAString(theNumber){
    var string = 'someArray' + theNumber[0].slice(0,1);
}
```

Is there an easy way to point to an array that is sequentially numbered?

Comment: Create a 2D array: `let arr = [someArray1, someArray2, someArray3]`. Then inside `grabAString` function: `return arr[theNumber - 1][0]`

Comment: what is `someArray1["someString", "anotherString"];` supposed to be exactly?

Comment: Your code is really a mess it's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. In grabAString, you are trying to index a number, which does not work.

If you want to access the first element of an array just do `array[0]`

Comment: You can not build a variable from a string.... too lazy to find the dupe on bracket syntax with window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign those arrays as properties of an object so you can use `[]` notation for dynamic property names

```js
const arrs = {
  someArray1 : ["someString", "anotherString"],
  someArray2 : ["someString", "anotherString"],
  someArray3 : ["someString", "anotherString"]

}
heresANumber = 1;


function grabAString(theNumber) {
  return arrs['someArray' + theNumber][0];
}

console.log( grabAString(heresANumber))
```

Comment: @mplungjan I know...not sure what expectation for `grabAString()` is

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array for ordered items.

```js
function grabAString(theNumber){
    return array[theNumber - 1];
}

var someArray1 = ["someString", "anotherString"],
    someArray2 = ["someString", "anotherString"],
    someArray3 = ["someString", "anotherString"],
    array = [someArray1, someArray2, someArray3],
    heresANumber = 1;

console.log(grabAString(heresANumber));
```

An advanced version takes an index, which is zero based like

```
0, ..., n - 1
```

and a direct access with the index.

Another solution could be to take [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) in an object where the variable names are the properties. This allows to access with a combined key.

```js
function grabAString(theNumber){
    return object['someArray' + theNumber];
}

var someArray1 = ["someString", "anotherString"],
    someArray2 = ["someString", "anotherString"],
    someArray3 = ["someString", "anotherString"],
    object = { someArray1, someArray2, someArray3 },
    heresANumber = 1;

console.log(grabAString(heresANumber));
```